# Websocket - Chrome complaining about mask bit set

Tags: erlang, websocket

I have implemented a websocket server in my existing server. Handshake is good and then I can even send first message and client browser receives it. But any subsequent messages disconnect websocket. On chrome I get following error.

```
failed: A server must not mask any frames that it sends to the client.
```

My frame is created like this

```
Len = erlang:size(Msg),
if
        Len < 126 ->
             Message = [<<1:1, 0:3,2:4,0:1,Len:7>>,Msg];
        Len < 65536 ->
             Message = [<<1:1, 0:3,2:4,0:1,126:7,Len:16>>,Msg];
        true ->
             Message = [<<1:1, 0:3,2:4,0:1,127:7,Len:64>>,Msg]
 end,
```

Now one sample data to be transmitted looks like this
    <<130,46,60,115,110,112,95,105,110,102,111,32,97,118,95,112,111,116,61,34,49,49,34,32,104,97,110,100,115,95,112,101,114,95,104,111,117,114,61,34,48,46,50,48,34,32,47,62>>

As you can see in the code above, my mask bit is always set to 0, but I don't why the same message works for the first time and then I send the same message again, it complains about mask bit set.

Anybody got any idea why?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The frame sample data you pasted is sane.

```
48 bytes
ErlangSampleBytes[48] = 82 2E 3C 73 6E 70 5F 69  6E 66 6F 20 61 76 5F 70
                        6F 74 3D 22 31 31 22 20  68 61 6E 64 73 5F 70 65
                        72 5F 68 6F 75 72 3D 22  30 2E 32 30 22 20 2F 3E
```

It Parses/Translates to:

```
82 = fin:true
     rsv1:false
     rsv2:false
     rsv3:false
     opcode:2
2E = masked:false
     payloadLength:46 (decimal)
Payload = UTF8 valid: 
     <snp_info av_pot="11" hands_per_hour="0.20" />
```

You don't even have a mismatch on the payload length declaration and what is left in the sample buffer.

At this point, it would be wise to look at the chrome inspection tooling to find out what the frames it thinks it got.  And a next step after that would be to try to capture the network traffic with a tool like WireShark in an effort to see what is going on.

Suspect that the # of bytes you are sending on the wire, vs what you are declaring in the payloadLength are differing.  (common one i've seen is sending more bytes than you declare)

Such as allocating a buffer of 1024 bytes, filling in the first 48 properly, then sending the entire 1024 bytes.  That will mess parsing of the next frame.

Comment: If Chrome complains about things like masking or special bits being set, that data usually doesn't make it into the network inspector.  You'll probably want to jump straight to something like WireShark (I've found Charles is enough, and a bit less complicated to use).

Comment: HI Thanks for the quick reply and sorry my late response. I have checked the traffic on wireshark now (chrome is not of much use). Now my first message is 941 bytes and second 251 bytes. For first message I can see 1 websocket section in wireshark but in second message I get 3 websocket messages (I will attach screenshot). First says payload length 2, second 121 and third 99. And in info it says, its continuation message.

Comment: In this image message number 1020114 is first message which is received correctly (Length is shown 1012 - not sure why, should be 941). 1020561 is the second message which is causing problem. Again length is 322 instead of 251.

Comment: Actually thanks i resolved it. I followed your suggestion of investigating byte length. My generic code was adding a delimitor after I calculated the length and it was sending the next frame as continuation frame. I removed the delimiter and it works fine.

Comment: @rameez82 another thing your image shows, is a TEXT [FIN] then a CONTINUATION frame. That is not allowed per the websocket spec.