# Wireshark shows correct WebSockets frame, Chrome complains reserved bits are set

Tags: google-chrome, websocket, wireshark

I am having a very similar problem to the one in: [Websocket - Chrome complaining about mask bit set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18641341/websocket-chrome-complaining-about-mask-bit-set). From what I can understand, the OP in that question was not correctly handling continuation packets, but in my problem, I only have one packet.

I wrote my own little websockets server, and I'm trying to get an echo server up and running. The following screenshot shows a Wireshark clip from my home computer (the WebSocket client). The selected packet is number 10.

[image: Wireshark shows good data]

According to Wireshark, this packet received on my home computer correctly has all the reserved bits set to zero. However, chrome complains:

[image: Chrome claims reserved bits are on]

I also used tcpdump on my server machine and confirmed that the correct data is being sent out (which isn't surprising, given that my home computer correctly receives good data).

Does anyone know why Chrome is complaining even though Wireshark thinks the WebSocket packet is AOK?

Answer (score 1):

Wow, right after posting the question I noticed something weird in the screenshot: the replied data (`0x00000031`) wasn't matching my sent data (`0x3132333435`, which is `"12345"` in ASCII).

It turns out I was still adding the mask into the packet header, which you're not supposed to do if you didn't set the MASK bit. I edited my server to not add the mask, and now the returned packet looks like:

[image: Removed mask in header]

The problem was that I was writing 4 bytes too many, and after Chrome parsed the packet with garbled payload (which included my unneeded mask in the header) the remaining 4 bytes spilled over into a new packet that had an invalid websockets frame. In other words, Chrome was complaining about a second websockets frame I was inadvertently sending.